# NavigationService remove forwardstack

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationservice

I see a lot of answers, about removing the backstack.

But How do I remove the forward stack?

Aka, Navigating A, to B, to C

A -> B -> C

I then navigate back from C, to B (Form saved, C closed `NavigationService.GoBack();`)

B <- C

I should now, NOT be able to navigate back to C using the forward button. But have no idea how to implement this. It makes most sense to remove it from the stack somehow.

Comment: Does anyone know how to achieve this? Still struggling with it.

Comment: Just an idea - when you in B and you somehow know you're back from C, repeat the navigation to B. This should make B the most recent visited element so no way to go to C.
Once again, just an idea - didn't give it a try.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov Thanks for your suggestion. I have checked if `CanGoForward` then navigate to a copy of itself (B2), and remove the backstack to remove the origional B. It seems like a hacky implementation. As it is essentially having to reload B. But i was reloading the data on the page anyway So not a massive hit. It is a solution, but wonder if there is a better one. Glad its working at least. Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to dig into NavigationService code - I recall there is a dependency property CanGoForward and some logic around its state so it might worth trying to set that property directly to false. An idea, again.

Comment: Did you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1908675/656243 .. it seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling None of the answers remove from the forward stack. And some answers don't work. I'm guessing its not possible, so I'll go with alternative functionality.

Comment: did you try to handle navigation event? I mean just cancel navigation forward. `NavigatingCancelEventArgs e; if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Forward) e.Cancel = true;`

Comment: @vadim_hr The arrow will still show it possible to go forward on navigation bar though?

Comment: have you tried cancelling it AND this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367876/how-disable-navigation-shortcuts-in-frame-c-sharp-wpf

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I'll give it all a try.

Comment: @Doomsknight `Page.goForwardButton.IsEnabled = false;`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was posted long ago, but recently I stumbled upon similar issue and this is how I solved it for my case. I hope it'll help someone.

**Requirement**

User should be able to go back to pages visited earlier but should not be able to go forward once back button is pressed.

**My Approach**

Create a custom control derived from `Frame` and add two addition DPs `AllowForwardNavigation` and `AllowBackNavigation` so that I can control if I want to allow prev/next navigation.

**MyFrame.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyFrame : Frame
{
    #region Dependency Properties
    public bool AllowForwardNavigation
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowForwardNavigationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AllowForwardNavigationProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowForwardNavigationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(AllowForwardNavigation), typeof(bool), typeof(MyFrame), new PropertyMetadata(true));

    public bool AllowBackNavigation
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowBackNavigationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AllowBackNavigationProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowBackNavigationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(AllowBackNavigation), typeof(bool), typeof(MyFrame), new PropertyMetadata(true));

    #endregion

    public MyFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        JournalOwnership = JournalOwnership.OwnsJournal;


        // find existing bindings
        var existingBindings = CommandBindings.OfType<CommandBinding>()
                                              .Where(x => x.Command == NavigationCommands.BrowseForward
                                                       || x.Command == NavigationCommands.BrowseBack)
                                              .ToArray();

        // remove existing bindings
        foreach (var binding in existingBindings)
            CommandBindings.Remove(binding);

        // add new binding
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.BrowseForward, OnGoForward, OnQueryGoForward));
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.BrowseBack, OnGoBack, OnQueryGoBack));

        // override default navigation behavior
        NavigationService.Navigating += NavigationService_Navigating;
    }

    private void NavigationService_Navigating(Object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.NavigationMode)
        {
            case NavigationMode.Forward:
                e.Cancel = !AllowForwardNavigation;
                break;
            case NavigationMode.Back:
                e.Cancel = !AllowBackNavigation;
                break;
        }
    }

    #region Command methods
    private void OnGoForward(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if (AllowForwardNavigation && NavigationService.CanGoForward)
            NavigationService.GoForward();
    }

    private void OnQueryGoForward(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        e.CanExecute = AllowForwardNavigation && NavigationService.CanGoForward;
    }

    private void OnGoBack(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if (AllowBackNavigation && NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            NavigationService.GoBack();
    }

    private void OnQueryGoBack(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        e.CanExecute = AllowBackNavigation && NavigationService.CanGoBack;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**MyFrame.xaml**

```
            <Style x:Key="NavigationWindowBackButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack"/>
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" Height="24" Width="24">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="Circle" Fill="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonFillEnabled}" Stroke="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonStrokeEnabled}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0.37,7.69 L5.74,14.20 A1.5,1.5,0,1,0,10.26,12.27 L8.42,10.42 14.90,10.39 A1.5,1.5,0,1,0,14.92,5.87 L8.44,5.90 10.31,4.03 A1.5,1.5,0,1,0,5.79,1.77 z" Fill="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationArrowFill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stroke="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationArrowStrokeEnabled}" StrokeThickness="0.75" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Circle" Value="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonFillDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Circle" Value="#B5BACE"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#B0B5BACE"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#D0FFFFFF"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Circle" Value="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonFillHover}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Circle" Value="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonFillPressed}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="NavigationWindowForwardButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="NavigationCommands.BrowseForward"/>
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" Height="24" Width="24">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="Circle" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonFillEnabled}" Stroke="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonStrokeEnabled}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Data="M0.37,7.69 L5.74,14.20 A1.5,1.5,0,1,0,10.26,12.27 L8.42,10.42 14.90,10.39 A1.5,1.5,0,1,0,14.92,5.87 L8.44,5.90 10.31,4.03 A1.5,1.5,0,1,0,5.79,1.77 z" Fill="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationArrowFill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0" Stroke="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationArrowStrokeEnabled}" StrokeThickness="0.75" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                </Path>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Circle" Value="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonFillDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Circle" Value="#B5BACE"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#B0B5BACE"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#D0FFFFFF"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Circle" Value="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonFillHover}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Circle" Value="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonFillPressed}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Frame.Resources>
    <Frame.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame">
            <DockPanel Margin="7">
                <StackPanel Visibility="{TemplateBinding NavigationUIVisibility}" Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal"
                            DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource NavigationWindowBackButtonStyle}"
                            Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack"
                            Content="M 4 0 L 0 4 L 4 8 Z"
                            Margin="2.7,0,1.3,0" />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource NavigationWindowForwardButtonStyle}"
                            Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseForward"
                            Content="M 4 0 L 0 4 L 4 8 Z" Margin="1.3,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Frame.Template>
</Frame>
```

**Usage**

```
<local:MyFrame x:Name="_mainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Visible" 
               AllowForwardNavigation="False" />
```